# Nginx directory forbidden 403 django

Tags: django, nginx, centos

I am trying to deploy django in centos 8 . I am getting 403 directory forbidden error. I have applied

```
chmod 755 var/www/
```

still i am getting this error

I have also applied **sudo chown myusername:psaserv /var/www/vhosts/aaa.com** but still i am getting this error . This is the error i am getting inside the server logs

```
2020/10/22 08:15:14 [error] 78481#0: *398 directory index of "/var/www/vhosts/aaa.com/httpdocs/djangoProject/" is forbidden, client: 162.158.167.71, server: aaa.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "aaa.com"
```

this is my nginx configuration file

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Comment: This isn't a permissions problem. It simply means that there is no `index.html` file in the `/var/www/vhosts/aaa.com/httpdocs/djangoProject/` directory.

Comment: i need to run the py file manage.py file , how would i do it? @RichardSmith

Comment: You need to setup some application server backend (usually uWSGI, but there are other choices), you can't use python scripts with a pure nginx. Read [How to use Django with uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) and [How to use uWSGI with nginx](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html) for the beginning. Additionally, this is global nginx configuration file and it can't help to solve your problem at all. Real configuration for your server should be somewhere under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to just make sure to allow your custom document root to be served as HTTP content.  To do so, try running :

`chcon -vR system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/vhosts/aaa.com`

this one bit me too just the other day =\

FYI - if you have SELinux installed and running, this is probably also why.  You either have to go through the lengthy process of resolving the SELinux problems, disable SELinux, or keep the files in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder.